# How to iterate a Java Object's properties in Play framework's template engine

Tags: templates, playframework

I've been using the Play framework and have had trouble iterating a Java Object's properties in playframework's template engine.

Comment: what do you mean iterating a object's properties. Do you mean iterating a list, or displaying the individual attributes of an object?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you are using Play 1.x and you want iterate a List of Object or an Array you can use **#{list}** built-in tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help

```
#{if books}//if books array exist
#{list books, as:'book'}

<div id="book">
<ul>
   ${book.title}
</ul>

#{/list}
```